# Huge Number of Ids in IN clause in Hadoop Hive query

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hdfs, bigdata

**Qn:** What's the best way to get one column (let's say item_name) from a table containing 9 million rows by passing a 700K item_ids in the `IN` clause

I am very new to Hadoop and Hive, I am coming from a Java background. Is there anyway/easyway to get it all at one go? Or do I need to chunk it? If I need to chunk, what will be the sweet number you suggest (I know it depends on numerous other factors, but just to get a starting point) Or will you suggest any other solution than hive(Something like a Java multi threaded batch hitting Hadoop with chunks of item_ids)

I tried already by sending 700K in the `IN` clause, it's choking, nothing came back, query was mysteriously killed.

Comment: JOIN perhaps? Load the 700K into a temp table and join the temp table with the table with the item_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options:

**Join.**
Put all id's into a file in HDFS, create table on top of file directory.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_ids(item_id int)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
location '/hive/data' --location(directory) in hdfs where the file is
;
select item_name from table a
      inner join table_ids b on a.item_id=b.item_id
```

**Using in_file:**
Put all ids into file, one id in a row.

```
select item_name from table where in_file(item_id, '/tmp/myfilename'); --local file
```

**Using join with stack, if it fits in memory:**

```
select item_name from table a
      inner join 
(
select stack(10, --the number of IDs, add more IDs
             0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9) as (item_id) 
 ) b
 on a.item_id=b.item_id
```

Comment: Thanks . Let me try that